# Autoplay audio file on active div

Tags: javascript, html, audio, autoplay, elementor

I'm terrible at JS and I've tried dozens of thing to make this work, but nothing seems to work for me.

I want AUDIO1 file to play and AUDIO2 file to pause automatically when certain div element has "elementor-active" class, and vice versa.

Any help appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="elementor-tab-title-1601" class="elementor-active">TAB 1</div><div id="elementor-tab-title-1602" class="">TAB 2</div>
<div id="TAB1" class="active" style="display: block;">
<audio id="AUDIO1" loop="loop">
<source src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/audio1.ogg">
<source src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio></div>
<div id="TAB2" class="">
<audio id="AUDIO2" loop="loop">
<source src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/audio2.ogg">
<source src="http://localhost/grad/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/audio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```js
var audio_one = new Audio('PATH_TO_AUDIO_1');
var audio_two = new Audio('PATH_TO_AUDIO_2');

var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('YOUR_BLOCK_SELECTOR').hasClass('active')) {
    audio_one.play();
    audio_two.pause();
  } else {
    audio_one.pause();
    audio_two.play();
  }
}, 250);
```